# SSRS Main/SubReport Page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a Main Report and a sub report placed in it.

When I run the report my sub report goes and starts from the next page.Instead I would like to have the sub report to start on the first page and then go to the next page.

Comment: change the layout? put subreport before the main one?

Comment: I cant do that ,my sub report has to start after the main report

Comment: Can you please show us what you mean?  "my sub report goes and starts from the next page.Instead I would like to have the sub report to start on the first page and then go to the next page" doesn't really make any sense...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `PageSize` within the Report properties to be big enough to contain both your Main and Sub report content.